# Ecto - migrate table column into its own join table (shifting the DATA to the new tables)

Tags: elixir, database-migration, ecto

I would like to go from this:

```
  schema "products" do
    field :name, :string
    field :brand, :string
    ...more fields...
  end
```

To this:

```
  schema "products" do
    field :name, :string
    ...more fields...
  end

  schema "brands" do
    field :name, :string
    ...more fields...
  end

  schema "product_brand_joins" do
    field :p_id, :integer
    field :b_id, :integer
    ...more fields...
  end
```

Without losing my current data which has products with a string :brand field.

I understand how to create the new brands table and product_brand_joins tables and remove ":brand" from products table, with an ecto migration. But is there a way to manipulate my current data into the new tables?

Comment: Steps should be
1. Create new `brands` table and `product_brand_joins` table.
2. Migrate data from `products` table to the new tables.
3. Delete the field in `products` table.
Your data stay safe!

Comment: Thanks @TheAnh, I am just unsure how to do the migrate data to new tables part. I have only migrated tables, not data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can execute SQL statements using the [`execute/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto_sql/Ecto.Migration.html#execute/1) or `execute/2` functions, the one that accepts two arguments is a rollbackable version of the first one, which expects a statement to execute when migrating and one to execute when rolling back.

So, you can use that to define what should happen when migrating and it becomes a matter of defining your statement. At the end of [this docs page from PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/dml-insert.html) there's an example of inserting based on a subquery, which we'll use here.

In your migration `.exs` file:

```rb
use Ecto.Migration

def up do
  create table(:brands) do
    add :name, :string,
    # add other fields
  end

  create table("product_brand_joins") do
    add :product_id, references: :products
    add :brand_id, references: :brands
  end

  # Insert into the brands table a brand with each name found in products
  execute(
    "INSERT INTO brands(name) 
      SELECT DISTINCT(brand) FROM products"
  )

  # Insert into the joined table the product and brand ids
  execute(
    "INSERT INTO product_brand_joins(product_id, brand_id)
      SELECT p.id, b.id FROM products p LEFT JOIN brands b ON p.brand = b.name"
  )

  # And finally delete the column from products
  alter table(:products) do
    remove :brand
  end
end
```

And then for the rollback you would implement the `down` function in the migration to revert the process using similar logic: creating the brand column in `products`, filling it with the name of the corresponding brand depending on the product id, and removing the new tables.